# simple stylesheet does not work in FireFox (font-size)

Tags: html, css

I add style change in html and surprisingly it does not work in FireFox but works well in IE, what can go wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body, h1, h2, h3, h4{font-size=24px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <h3>From - 456 To - a7890: 26 mins - 20.6 km</h3>
        <h4>Spot 1 To Spot B</h4>
        <hr>
        <br>heading towards east for 40 miles<hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is invalid css. Instead of `=` use `:`

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body, h1, h2, h3, h4 {font-size:24px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <h3>From - 456 To - a7890: 26 mins - 20.6 km</h3>
        <h4>Spot 1 To Spot B</h4>
        <hr>
        <br>heading towards east for 40 miles<hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't use the equals symbol in CSS. This is what you want

```
    <style>
        body, h1, h2, h3, h4{font-size:24px;}
    </style>
```